# Exclude fields of filtered array elements with 1 $project stage

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Consider the schema below:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("56b9bfb962debd68f8b61340"), 
    "Name" : "Parent", 
    "Children" : [
        {
            "Name" : "A", 
            "Age" : NumberInt(0)
        }, 
        {
            "Name" : "B", 
            "Age" : NumberInt(1)
        }, 
        {
            "Name" : "C", 
            "Age" : NumberInt(2)
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm using 2 $project stages. 1 to filter "Children" and another to select fields except "Children.Age":

```
db.collection.aggregate(
  [
    {
      $project: {
        Name: 1,
        Children: { $filter: {
          input: "$Children",
          as: "child",
          cond: { $gt: ["$$child.Age", 0] }
        } }
      }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        Name: 1,
        Children: { Name: 1 }
      }
    }
  ]
);
```

Can I do it using only 1 $project stage?

I'd like to avoid using $unwind and $group if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can shorten your pipeline to one stage. To do that you need to use the [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) operator.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": { 
        "Name": 1, 
        "children": { 
            "$map": { 
                "input": { 
                    "$filter": { 
                        "input": "$Children", 
                        "as": "child", 
                        "cond": { "$gt": [ "$$child.Age", 0 ] } 
                    } 
                }, 
                "as": "ch", 
                "in": 
                "$$ch.Name" 
            } 
        } 
    }} 
])
```

Another alternative is using the [`$setDifference`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/) operator and the `$map` operator operator. But as mentioned in the documentation:

> `$setDifference` filters out duplicates in its result to output an array that contain only unique entries.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": { 
        "Name": 1, 
        "Children": { 
            "$setDifference": [ 
                { "$map": { 
                    "input": "$Children", 
                    "as": "child", 
                    "in": { 
                        "$cond": [ 
                            { "$gt": [ "$$child.Age", 0 ] }, 
                            "$$child.Name", 
                            false 
                        ] 
                    } 
                }}, 
                [false]
            ] 
        }
    }}
])
```

Which returns:

```js
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("56b9bfb962debd68f8b61340"),
        "Name" : "Parent",
        "Children" : [
                "B",
                "C"
        ]
}
```

Comment: In the first solution: If I whant to exclude 1 field, and include at least 2 fields?